# How can i show checkbox in Odoo 12?

Tags: checkbox, module, odoo, odoo-12

I want to show checkbox in Odoo 12. I try with my code but it's not working Please help me.
Here is my code of module.

```
class ProductTemplate(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    field_name1 = fields.Boolean(string="Product Barcode Generator")
```

Here is view Code:

```
   <record id="product_template_form_parent_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">product.template.form.parent.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">product.template</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//notebook" position="inside">
                <page string="Product Barcode Generator">
                    <label for="field_name1"/>
                    <field name="field_name1" />
                </page>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Comment: Did you add your `.py` file in `__init__.py` and `.xml` file in `__manifest__.py`?

Comment: Update your question add your `__init__.py` and `__manifest__.py` file in code also add your current folder structure where you had added your module.

Comment: How can i add .py file in __init__.py and .xml file in __manifest__.py.??

Comment: Refer this link (https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/howtos/backend.html)

Comment: Yes i have added file and it's working fine for field but it's not working for checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try:

Your External Id should be:

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_only_form_view"/>
```